# Image not showing using useState hook in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I used useState hook and called the memeData images with handler onClick on a button. I dont know the issue why it is not showing my image. Either there isn't any error in console or in terminal.

Here is the image of my output
[image: OUTPUT IMAGE]

Can anybody help??? Thank you in advance!

ok, so here is my code from componenet/MemeForm.js

```
// import memeData from "../memeData"
import React from "react"
import memeData from "../memeData"


export default function MemeForm() {

    const [memeImage, setMemeImage] = React.useState("")

    function GetMemeImage() {
        const MemeArray = memeData.data.GirlImages

        const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * MemeArray.length)
        // const url = MemeArray[randomNumber].url

        setMemeImage(MemeArray[randomNumber].url)
    }

    return (
        <main>
            <form className="form">
                <div className="top-body">
                    <div className="form-inner">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Top Text" className="form-input" />

                        <input type="text" placeholder="Bottom Text" className="form-input" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button onClick={GetMemeImage} className="form-button">Get a new meme image </button>
            </form>
            <img src={memeImage} className="meme--image" alt="img" />
        </main>
    )
}
```

Next is memeData.js code

```
const memeData = {
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "GirlImages": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "description": "Lady with a Teddy",
                "url": "https://unsplash.com/photos/n1bDxmYK_94"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "description": "Girl with camera",
                "url": "https://unsplash.com/photos/JnD8e1Bx9Ck"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "description": "Beautiful Girl with Glasses",
                "url": "https://unsplash.com/photos/xNbpmXAVdA8"
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "description": "Redhead with frackles",
                "url": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3228213/pexels-photo-3228213.jpeg"
            },
            {
                "id": "5",
                "description": "Girl in black dress",
                "url": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1385472/pexels-photo-1385472.jpeg"
            },
            {
                "id": "6",
                "description": "Girl Sitting on Chair",
                "url": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/4725133/pexels-photo-4725133.jpeg"
            }
        ]
    }
}

export default memeData
```

Comment: Only half of the `url` values in the array are URLs to image assets. The other half are links to a web page that displays an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<button>` tag placed within a `<form>` tag are by default `type='submit'`. You have two solutions.

1. `<button type="button">` This allows a button to function as a normal button and won't trigger the form submission. This is probably what you want.
2. You can also modify the function as below to prevent the default behavior (which is the form submission)

```js
function GetMemeImage(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
```

Plus, some of your URLs are not working but that's a minor issue.

Here's a working demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-babbage-5wyzld?file=/src/App.js:192-244